# Make a Button look like an Ellipse and then Bind the Color of it

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, bind, ellipse

This is my XAML makiing a Style where the Button looks like an Ellipse.
I had also made the color with a key so i can change or even bind it(not with any luck).
The problem with the binding is that i dont have a Name to bind with the DataContent.

```
    <Color x:Key="Player1C" >Gray</Color>


    <Style x:Key="Player11" x:Name="Pl1style" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Name="EllipsePl1" Width="30" Height="30" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Player1C}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have tried to do this in C# `Player1 = new Style(typeof(Button));
            Player1.Setters.Add(new Setter(Ellipse.FillProperty, new SolidColorBrush(GameInstance.Color1)));`

But i just get a Button

I then created a ControlTemplate , a grid ,an ellipse and filled the ellipse in order to copy exactly the XAML

```
            ControlTemplate ct1 = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
        Grid agrid = new Grid();
        Ellipse el1 = new Ellipse();
        el1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

But i get error when i try to do `Player1.Setters.Add(new Setter(ct1 etc etc)`

Any help will be much appreciated , either a Binding with the XAML or a way to do it in c sharp.
I have also tried creating my own class of button but had again problems.

Comment: Is this is wat u looking for http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32257/A-Style-for-Round-Glassy-WPF-Buttons

Comment: no ? my problem is that i want to bind the the Fill effect of the ellipse.. i dont see how the article helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<Style x:Key="Player11" x:Name="Pl1style" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Name="EllipsePl1" Width="30" Height="30" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Player1C}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Resources.Add("Player1C",Colors.Black);
         DataContext = this;

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resources["Player1C"] = Colors.Red;
    }
```

This is one of the many ways you can do in c# .However you can also do it using Trigger. Using Binding You can do it this way.

```
  <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Cols, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry images are not clear just Zoom them they will be visible.I am  new to stackoverflow so dnt know how to add code.

Comment: 4 spaces to start a line will convert it to code. Also make sure you have 1 empty line before the start of a __chunk__ of code

Comment: it actually works , i will also try the trigger when i fully finish this , Thx a milion man

Comment: No problem, using DynamicResources is not a good approach you must go with Binding @drakoumelitos. Thanks alot Kshitij for letting me know how to add code here.

Comment: ye but the problem is when i try to do the Datacontext i cant get the property i want to add it to for example : 

(EllipseName).DataContext = this; doesnt work coz it cant find the name of the ellipse

Comment: You dont need to set the DataContext of the Ellipse just try the small piece of code shown above .Here Cols is the property of type Color.

Comment: Ill try that after i finish my whole program ,thnx anyway :D

Comment: while i was working on this program i found another error <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Player1C}"/> is not recognized by xaml so the button doesnt have a style only color . I need to know which style it has. any help ?

Comment: @ethicallogics
center.Style = (Style)FindResource(GameInstance.GameBoardList[0]._ID); for some reason now this wont get any style... I use that to reset the styles but now the buttons dont even have a style style.basedon is null

Comment: you need to pass exactly same key as it is been used in xaml.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the fill color of ellipse to the background of the button. So you simply have to change the background of the button.

Template :

```
<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
```